# Applying method to all methods, using result

Tags: python, functional-programming

When dabbling in functional languages, I recall a way to call a method on a list of objects, where the next method call used the result of the previous call as input as well as the next list item.

In Python, the following code does the same thing using a for-loop (in this instance, it builds a binary tree based on a list of integers). Assume binary_insert takes a tree and an integer as arguments.

```
t = None
for x in [4, 2, 1, 5, 6, 3, 7, 9, 8, 12, 10, 11, 13, 15, 14]:
    t = binary_insert(t, x)
print t
```

Basically I'm trying to remember the name of that kind of function application. If there's a Python equivalent, that would be brilliant.

Comment: In functional languages it is often called `fold`.

Comment: You're right - that's the name I know it by. Thanks!

Comment: I think in python it is called `reduce`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

> reduce(function, sequence[, initial]) -> value
>
> Apply a function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of a sequence,
> from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.
> For example, reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates
> ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5).  If initial is present, it is placed before the items
> of the sequence in the calculation, and serves as a default when the
> sequence is empty.

Comment: Note that in python3 it's not available in the global namespace. You have to import it from `functools`.